# How to create an array of 100 random strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, random, malloc

I'm trying to create an array of 100 strings of random sizes between 3 and 10 letters long in C but I'm having a bit of trouble. This is what I have so far...

```
int main() {
    int count, number;
    char *randomWord[100]; // 1-d array of pointers to char
    char randomLetter;
    int wordLength;

    // generate 100 strings or random sizes between 3 and 10 letters
    for (count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
        wordLength = ((rand() % 10) + 3);  // get random size of word
        randomWord[count] = malloc(wordLength + 1); // allocated space for word
        for (number = 1; number < wordLength; number++) {
            randomLetter = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
            //randomWord[count] =
            printf("%d\n", randomLetter);
        }

        printf("%d\n", &randomWord[count]);
    }
}
```

The output I get looks like this...

```
72
90
82
73
87
75
66
65
6356712
88
66
71
70
67
66
67
69
89
72
74
6356716
71
73
88
87
6356720
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: try `printf("%d\n", &randomWord[count]);` with %s instead of %d, but make sure you zero-terminate the strings before.

Comment: What do you think `&randomWord[count]` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- You do not store the characters into the allocated arrays.
- You compute one random letter too few, starting the loop at `0` would fix this.
- You do not print the words, but merely their addresses.

Here is how to fix the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int count, number;
    char *randomWord[100]; // 1-d array of pointers to char

    // generate 100 strings or random sizes between 3 and 10 letters
    for (count = 0; count < 100; count++) {
        int wordLength = 3 + rand() % 8;  // get random word size in 3..10
        randomWord[count] = malloc(wordLength + 1); // allocated space for word
        for (number = 0; number < wordLength; number++) {
            randomWord[count][number] = 'A' + rand() % 26;
        }
        randomWord[count][number] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", randomWord[count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, as you know for sure, you do not write into `randomWord[count]`, such that you cannot print out the result later.

Second, you'd need to terminate each string with `\0`, and you should use `printf("%s\n", randomWord[count]);`, i.e. without the `&` and with `%s`. Not terminating a string and using it in `printf("%s"...` very likely yields undefined behaviour; When printing a string, use `%s`, not `%d`. And when using `%s`, `printf` requires a pointer to the first character of the string. As you defined `char *randomWord[100]`, `randomWord[count]` stands for such a pointer to a character, whereas `&randomWord[count]` would stand for the address of the pointer, not of the string's first character.

```
wordLength = ((rand() % 10) + 3);  // get random size of word
randomWord[count] = malloc(wordLength + 1); // allocated space for word
for(number = 0; number < wordLength; number++)
{
    randomLetter = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
    randomWord[count][number] = randomLetter;
    // printf("%c", randomLetter);
}
randomWord[count][wordLength] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", randomWord[count]);
```

BTW: Note that `(rand() % 10) + 3)` gives random lengths between `3` and `12`, not between `3` and `10`.

Comment: You may want to comment additionally on just how wrong `&randomWord[count]` is and what that actually does.

Comment: @David C. Rankin: Done. Hope it helps OP.

Comment: Good job. That was just wonky as heck and indicated a clear misunderstanding of what was going on. I'm sure it will help. Letting that misconception go would just be down right dangerous.... (not the mention the *Undefined Behavior* invoked by printing the pointer address with `%d`)...

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using the wrong format specifier:

`%d` is used to output a signed decimal integer.
`%c` is used to output a character.

Your inner `printf` should become : `printf("%c\n", randomLetter)`

Answer (score 0):

I won't plow the same ground plowed by the other answers. You now understand that:

```
printf("%d\n", &randomWord[count]);
```

was attempting to print the *address of the pointer* `randomWord[count]` and not at all the character you were attempting to print the ASCII value of. Remember `&` is the *address of* unary operator while `*` is the *dereference* operator. (which was invoking *Undefined Behavior* by attempting to print a pointer address with the `%d` format specifier. Use `%p` to print addresses)

Rather than invent each character from a *modulo* operation, it may be easier to simply pick a random index from a literal `A-Za-z0-9` (or whatever character set you wish to include). It is really "six to one" a "half-dozen to another", but it may be conceptually easier to keep track of what you are doing.

Before looking at an alternative, let's address using *magic numbers* in your code. (don't do it). If you need constants for use in your code, then `#define` them or use a global `enum` to do the same. For example, if you need constants for the *minimum length* of string to generate (say `MINL`) and max length `MAXL` or the maximum number of strings `MAXS` (and the number of characters to choose from `NCHR`), you can simply define constants with:

```
enum { MINL = 3, MAXL = 10, NCHR = 62, MAXS = 100 };
```

That way you have a single convenient location at the top of your code to adjust values as required -- without having to pick through your variable and loop declarations to do it.

Now the alternative. You can simply declare a string literal `alpha` with the characters you wish to create `100` random strings from. Then all that is required is to get a random length for each, allocate `length + 1` bytes of storage, and create `length` random numbers between `0` and `NCHR - 1` assigning the character to the indexes in your string and nul-terminating at the end.

(**note:** by using `calloc`, you have already filled the final byte in each string with zero, effectively providing for nul-termination, but it is good practice to affirmatively nul-terminate each string)

Putting that altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum { MINL = 3, MAXL = 10, NCHR = 62, MAXS = 100 };

int main (void) {

    char *alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"  /* NCHR long literal */
                  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"  /* of chars to shuffle */
                  "0123456789",
        *a[MAXS] = { NULL };        /* array of pointers to char  */
    int modlen = MAXL - MINL + 1;   /* mod length for 3 - 10 char */

    srand (time (NULL));            /* seed random number generator */

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXS; i++) {    /* loop to create MAXS strings */
        int len = rand() % modlen + MINL;       /* get length 3 - 10 */
        if (!(a[i] = calloc (len + 1, 1))) {    /* allocate memory */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhausted 'a[%d]'.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)       /* loop over len chars */
            a[i][j] = alpha[rand() % NCHR]; /* assing char from alpha */
        a[i][len] = 0;              /* affirmatively nul-terminate */
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAXS; i++) {        /* output results */
        printf ("a[%2d] : %s\n", i, a[i]);
        free (a[i]);        /* don't forget to free your memory */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_randshuffle
a[ 0] : KhwC0FhKv
a[ 1] : j4U4zwfHf
a[ 2] : vSd
a[ 3] : 4jWlzWJ725
a[ 4] : q9h
a[ 5] : sxYmHSZ1w
a[ 6] : WSPot
a[ 7] : hTD
a[ 8] : GXQ
a[ 9] : NJD3GksyYE
a[10] : dUvVGPrWe
....
a[92] : vHl5
a[93] : 5LZjkFYl
a[94] : Q4Y
a[95] : 67sWds
a[96] : YlQWDuFKV8
a[97] : PHJwrOLQ6b
a[98] : U0EPiarOi
a[99] : zyZ2gcB2aw
```

Look over all the answers. There are good points made. Then let us know if you have any further questions.